# ASP.Net Core OData 8 Query Options not showing up in Swagger UI

Tags: odata

I've created an ASP.Net Core OData 8 service and enabled Swagger generation and the Swagger UI however my OData endpoints do not show any query options in the Swagger UI.

All query options are enabled globally per below:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
   options => options.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents(
       "odata",
       modelBuilder.GetEdmModel(),
       builder => builder.AddSingleton<IODataSerializerProvider, CustomODataSerializerProvider>()));
```

`Get()` methods returning `IQueryable(s)` on my controllers are labeled with the `[EnableQuery]` attribute.

I am able to successfully execute all standard OData queries against my entity sets (filter, select, order by, etc)

However, the list of query options in Swagger UI is empty (no query parameters are shown in the Swagger generated spec for the API either).  Is this a known issue?  I've seen reports of this behavior in earlier versions of `ASP.Net` Core and `OData` (and some workarounds based on customizing Swagger behaviors with a custom operation filter), but my understanding is this is supposed to work in the latest ASP.Net `Core/OData` versions.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Swagger UI may not automatically generate OData query options in ASP.NET Core OData services, even with the [EnableQuery] attribute. While this is a known issue, there are workarounds. One common approach is to use custom operation filters to manually add these query parameters ($filter, $orderby, etc.) to the Swagger documentation. Another is to use the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.OData package designed to integrate Swagger with OData. Note that these are not official solutions, so it might be worth reporting the issue for further investigation on the respective GitHub repositories.

Comment: Thank you.  I posted on the OData / AspNetCoreOData project and was told something similar.  I was pointed to the dotnet / aspnet-api-versioning project as a solution.  I had looked at this before but was uncertain it would resolve the issue, but based on the pointer I tried again.  The project - in addition to adding API versioning support - has some ability to generate more detailed API specifications including OData parameters.  I was able to successfully integrate it and generate both Swagger pages and OpenAPI specs with more detailed API documentation including OData query parameters.